# Sorting a list of dicts by dict values

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have the following list of dictionaries

```
a = [{23:100}, {3:103}, {2:102}, {36:103}, {43:123}]
```

How can I sort it to get:

```
a = [{43:123}, {3:103}, {36:103}, {2:102}, {23:100}]
```

I mean, to sort the list by its dicts' values, in descending order.

Comment: Each of those dictionaries have different keys. Is there a better data type for this?

Answer (score 6):

In addition to brandizzi's answer, you could go with:

```
sorted(a, key=dict.values, reverse=True)
```

Pretty much the same thing, but possibly more idiomatic.

Comment: +1 I agree, this is the better answer unless the question specifies that only the first item be used for the sort.

Comment: hey, how can I extract the value from sorted `a` dict to recive int ?
e.g. 
`for b in a: 
     print a[i].keys()
     i+=1`
but python says it is still a list, I need to recive int. How can I do it ?

Comment: @user1403568 try `for b in a: print b.keys()[0]`. that will extract the keys, so you will end up printing out: 43, 3, 36, 2, 23. If you want values instead (like 123,103,36,102,100), use `b.values()[0]`.

Comment: Am I the only one getting the error: `'<' not supported between instances of 'dict_values' and 'dict_values'`?

Comment: @FrancescoBoi , how did you solve that error

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda i: i.values()[0], reverse=True)
[{43: 123}, {3: 103}, {36: 103}, {2: 102}, {23: 100}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a [`key`](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Key_Functions) parameter to the `list.sort()` method, so the comparison will be made in function of the returning value of `key`:

```
>>> a = [{23:100}, {3:103}, {2:102}, {36:103}, {43:123}]
>>> a.sort(key=lambda d: d.values()[0], reversed=True)
>>> a
[{23: 100}, {2: 102}, {3: 103}, {36: 103}, {43: 123}]
```

In this case, the key is a function which receives a dictionary `d` and gets a list of its value with `.values()`. Since there is just one value, we get this only value from the returned list. Then, the `list.sort()` method will compare those returned values, instead of the dictionaries themselves, when sorting.

Comment: This give a sort in increasing order, the OP wanted decreasing.

Comment: @raym0nd ok, repaired, although I should say I would prefer HodfHod solution anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

In python 3, the other answers no longer work because [`dict.values()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) now returns a dict view object rather than a list. To extract the value from the view object, we can use a combination of [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) and [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

```
a.sort(key=lambda dic: next(iter(dic.values())), reverse=True)
```

Comment: +1 because I don't think this *deserves* a downvote. However, I don't see how this is substantially different to @KurzedMetal's solution. Don't think `list.sort` vs `sorted(list)` merits two different solutions.

Comment: @jpp The thing is that `itervalues` doesn't exist in py3. I guess I could've edited that answer, but it would've been quite a substantial edit with the link to `iter` and `next` and everything.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather use (or at least keep in mind) `.itervalues()`

```
In [25]: sorted(a, key=lambda x: next(x.itervalues()), reverse=True)
Out[25]: [{43: 123}, {36: 103}, {2: 102}, {23: 100}, {3: 103}]
```